# RoutePrefix per controller that is relative to root/global route?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, routes, asp.net-web-api2

I am currently declaring the RoutePrefix attribute on each controller that defines the same pre-prefix for each controller. I've seen examples where the RoutePrefix seems to be relative but I can't reproduce this.

**What I Have:**

```
[RoutePrefix("api/v{version:int}/Vehicles") 
public class VehiclesController : ApiController {...}

[RoutePrefix("api/v{version:int}/Person}") 
public class PersonController : ApiController {...}
```

**What I'd like to do:**

```
[RoutePrefix("Vehicles") 
public class VehiclesController : ApiController {...}

[RoutePrefix("Person}") 
public class PersonController : ApiController {...}
```

and then be able to define the beginning ("api/v{version:int}" of the route globally in route registration.

Is this supported?